# How to retrieve innertext using capybara and poltergeist?

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara, nokogiri, poltergeist

I have this simple HTML:

```
<div> Test <span> someting </span></div>
```

How can I retrieve only the `innertext` of the div?

Using `text` retrieves all text from the div:

```
[1] pry(#<SandBox>)> first(:xpath, '//div').text
=> "Test someting"
```

Using `text()` in my XPath query results in the following error:

```
[2] pry(#<SandBox>)> first(:xpath, '//div/text()')
Capybara::Poltergeist::BrowserError: There was an error inside the PhantomJS portion of Poltergeist. This is probably a bug, so please report it. 
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'window.getComputedStyle(element).display')
```

However, using the same XPath with Nokogiri works:

```
[3] pry(#<SandBox>)> Nokogiri::HTML(page.html).xpath('//div/text()').text
=> " Test "
```

Is there a way to do it using only capybara without resorting to Nokogiri?

Comment: as the error message reports, this is very much likely a bug. You should report this to the developers. There is really no way around using `text()` and if this doesn't work I would consider it a major bug. So you either wait for the fix or you use another solution like Nokogiri

Comment: I too searched and it seems there is no way to get the inner HTML at this time. I guess we'll have to wait for an update or make a pull request. I think at least one other Capybara driver supports the innerHTML method.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Nokogiri and open-uri.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

2.2.0 :021 > html = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<div> Test <span> someting     </span></div>').child

 => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x44a7082 name="div" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x44a63ee " Test ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x44a62e0 name="span" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x44a3f04 " someting ">]>]>
```

Then you can perform operations on it depending on what you want to grab. So for the text inside the tags:

```
2.2.0 :072 > html.children.first

 => #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x45ea37c " Test "> 

2.2.0 :073 > html.children.first.text

=> " Test "
```

or

```
2.2.0 :215 > html.children.first.content

 => " Test "
```

Good luck!

Comment: I should mention, the reason you use #child on :021 is so that you are working with a Nokogiri::XML::Element. The Element class inherits from the Node class.